# save post data into file via php

Tags: php, html

I am using a simple HTML form to send http post request in this format: `key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&key4=value4&key5=value5` and i am trying to save the http post data into a text file using **PHP**

**This is the **PHP** code I came up with:**

```
$data1 = $_POST['key1'] ;
$data2 =$_POST['key2'] ;
$data3 =$_POST['key3'] ;
$data4 =$_POST['key4'];
$data5 =$_POST['key5'];
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $_POST['data1'], $_POST['data2'], $_POST['data3'], $_POST['data4'], $_POST['data5']);
fclose($fp);
```

but its only creating the file "data.txt" and not adding any of the values into the text file

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: `file_put_contents( 'data.txt',  json_encode( $_POST ) )` would probably be a good bet as it would allow easy decoding and access to the original data later?

Comment: Yes, `file_put_contents` with the `FILE_APPEND` flag (OP's `fopen` runs `a`), along with `json_encode` (probably with `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag if he intends to read it directly), would seem to be the useful way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query string parameters should be accessed with `$_GET`, even if the request method is POST.

Also, indexes `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, `data4`, and `data5` don't exist in request.

`fwrite` accepts at most 3 arguments.

Final code should be like this:

```
<?php

$data1 = $_REQUEST['key1'];
$data2 = $_REQUEST['key2'];
$data3 = $_REQUEST['key3'];
$data4 = $_REQUEST['key4'];
$data5 = $_REQUEST['key5'];
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, implode("\n", [$data1, $data2, $data3, $data4, $data5]));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: nope , doesnt work as i intended , this code doesnt create a file , it only shows the content of the php file "the code " in the response of form submit

Comment: @Arad016 You should start PHP tag with `<?php` at the beginning of your script (edited the answer).

Comment: You **should** add `<?php` at the beginning of this code.

Comment: its not showing the content at the submit page but its not adding the values into the text file either , it only creates the data.txt file and creates 5 rows but no data on those rows

Comment: Check if parameters exist in query string (edited the answer).

Comment: i am using this file on the wordpress website which i am sure i have the write access to and the form is also on the same website
and yes the post request do have the values because when i send it to a separate webserver , i receive the values correctly

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
fwrite($fp, $_POST['data1'], $_POST['data2'], $_POST['data3'], $_POST['data4'], $_POST['data5']);
```

To

```
fwrite($fp, "$data1,$data2,$data3,$data4,$data5");
```

All those "data" variables you defined are individuals, they aren't part of the $_POST array.

And fwrite expects a single string of data not a set of separate ones, so you need to concatenate them together. I put commas between them so you've got some chance of telling them apart but obviously you can change it to suit your requirements. Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

P.S. if your variables are being sent in the URL querystring (rather than the body of the request) then you need to use $_GET to retrieve them instead, like this:

```
$data1 = $_GET['key1'];
$data2 = $_GET['key2'];
$data3 = $_GET['key3'];
$data4 = $_GET['key4'];
$data5 = $_GET['key5'];
```

Comment: If you see the PHP code displayed on the page that means you either haven't got PHP set up properly or you tried to run it inside a file which doesn't have a .php extension

Comment: its only adding 4 comas "  ,,,,  " into the file

Comment: i forgot about adding the php tag at the beginning of the code now that i have added the tag , now its only showing the commas

Comment: "its only showing the commas"...where? on the screen, or in the file? Please be clear and precise when describing what is happening.

Comment: P.S. if those values are being sent on the querystring (rather than in the body of your request - again it wasn't really clear in the question then you'd have to use GET to retrieve them. See edited answer.